# Plotting dates with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've been attempting to plot data from a comma delimited csv file which contains a date and a float:

```
Date,Price (€)
01062017,20.90
02062017,30.90
03062017,40.90
04062017,60.90
05062017,50.90
```

I then attempt to plot this with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime

dates,cost = np.loadtxt('price_check.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1,unpack=True)

xdates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(int(date)),'%d%m%Y') for date in dates]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(xdates, cost,'o-',label='Cost')
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.ylabel('Price (Euro)')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('sunglasses_cost.png')
plt.show()
```

However, when the data is plotted, it looks like the leading zero in in the date string is being dropped:

[image]

Is there an easy way for the full date to be used in the plot?

Comment: Why are you turning your date to integer before giving it to `datetime.datetime.strptime()`? That's what kills your leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the dates, which are converted to integers and loose their leading zero. Then
 `"01062017"` becomes `1062017` and is then interpreted as `(2017, 6, 10, 0, 0)`,  so 2 digits as day, one digit month. For `5062017`, because there is no 50th of june, it is interpreted differently and correctly as `(2017, 6, 5, 0, 0)`.

The least invasive method to overcome this would be to format the string such that it always has 8 digist before datetime conversion:

```
xdates = [datetime.datetime.strptime('{:08}'.format(int(date)),'%d%m%Y') for date in dates]
```

This will then result in the correct plot. However, the xticklabels may show in an inconvenient way. This could be adjusted by choosing some locator and formatter

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

[image: enter code here]

As a last comment: If you have the choice to select the format of your input file, it might be worth specifing it in a non-ambiguous way, e.g. `20170601`.